# Display hidden table row screws up rest of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having trouble with hiding and showing table rows. I have code which is working most of the time to hide and show table rows based on their "hidden" attribute. The  elements are given an attribute  which gets the css of "display:none" and when the attribute is removed via JS, the default of "display:table-row" is restored. However this is still causing occasional weirdness in the following table rows. To make this even more complex, I only seem to see the problem on my 5k iMac screen and not on the regular monitor I use as a second screen. Any thoughts?

*EDIT*

Here's the code:

```
<table class="clauseTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>1</th>
     <th>2</th>
     <th>3</th>
     <th>4</th>
     <th>5</th>
     <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tagsTable">
  <tr playbookid="670" id="6878" value="6878">
     <td id="tagName">Name</td>
     <td id="required" class="clauseTable--radioContainer required undefined">

     </td>
     <td id="rejected" class="clauseTable--radioContainer rejected undefined">

     </td>
     <td id="conditional" class="clauseTable--radioContainer conditional selected">

     </td>
     <td id="ignore" class="clauseTable--radioContainer ignore undefined ">

     </td>
     <td id="editBtn" class="editClauseBtn"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tagsDescriptionsRow6878" class="conditional--row tagsDescriptionsRow" hidden="hidden">
     <td colspan="6">

     </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the SCSS:

```
tr {
      display: table-row;
      &[hidden='hidden'] {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

---

[image: Before the click]

---

[image: After removing hidden]

Comment: could be a problem with the styling of the `screen-width` but could you show us your code so that we can take a better look at it

Comment: Trying to figure out a way to show the code without showing confidential info. Hang on...

Comment: No problem, just add it, for example, in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with some lorem ipsum text

Comment: Added code. Too much extra markup and styles to port it to jsfiddle.

Comment: @Deathstorm can you elaborate on what kinds of problems screen-width could cause?  This problem is ONLY happening on my retina screens.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be simpler and safer to use a class instead of the "hidden" attribute.

```
tr.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

instead of

```
tr {
  display: table-row;
  &[hidden='hidden'] {
    display: none;
  }
}
```